how to modify wall clock time date time into correct timezone with dst time using Howard Hinnant's library
I have wall clock date time which has no time zone or DST effect. Left-hand side is what I have and right-hand side is what I need.
     Source time         Time I need
  14-03-2021 00:00     14-03-2021 00:00 EST
  14-03-2021 01:00     14-03-2021 01:00 EST
  14-03-2021 02:00     14-03-2021 03:00 EDT --> add DST offset from this entry to get correct time
  14-03-2021 03:00     14-03-2021 04:00 EDT --> keep on adding..

  6-Nov-21 23:00       7-Nov-21 00:00 EDT  
  7-Nov-21 00:00       7-Nov-21 01:00 EDT  --> keep on adding
  7-Nov-21 01:00       7-Nov-21 01:00 EDT  --> do not add DST offset
  7-Nov-21 02:00       7-Nov-21 02:00 EST  --> do not add till next DST start

I need to give DST effect from March 14, 2021 2:00 am to all subsequent times from start of DST till end of DST. Also in November I am expecting to remove this effect and continue the same until the next DST start date.
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "date/tz.h"

int main() 
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;
    auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    zoned_time zt{tz, sys_seconds{}};
    for (local_seconds tp = local_days{March/14/2021} + 0h;
         tp <= local_days{March/14/2021} + 3h; tp += 1h)
    {
        std::cout << "input time: " << tp << std::endl;
        
        zt = {zt.get_time_zone(), tp, choose::latest};
        auto utctime = zt.get_sys_time();
        auto info = zt.get_info();
        auto utcoffset = floor<seconds>(info.offset);
        auto dst_hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(info.save);
        auto dst_minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(info.save - dst_hours);
        auto newtime = utctime + utcoffset + dst_hours + dst_minutes;
        cout << "output time:" << newtime << endl;
    }
}

What I am getting is:
input time: 2021-03-14 00:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 00:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 01:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 01:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 04:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 03:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 04:00:00

What I want is:
input time: 2021-03-14 00:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 00:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 01:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 01:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 03:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 04:00:00

I am trying to figure out exact date and time of DST start. In above code when DST is starting an extra hour is getting added into it for 2:00 am entry.
I can see info structure for this entry (March 14, 2021 2:00 am) is showing start and end of DST, but not sure how to use it efficiently.

The smallest change from the existing code to get the desired output is just to remove almost everything from the loop:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "date/tz.h"

int main() 
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    zoned_time zt{tz, sys_seconds{}};
    for (local_seconds tp = local_days{March/14/2021};
         tp <= local_days{March/14/2021} + 3h; tp += 1h)
    {
        std::cout << "input time: " << tp << std::endl;
        
        zt = {zt.get_time_zone(), tp, choose::latest};
        cout << "output time:" << zt.get_local_time() << endl;
    }
}

Output:
input time: 2021-03-14 00:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 00:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 01:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 01:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 03:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00

The library does the computation for you.  There is no need to manually retrieve the UTC offset and the extra DST offset.  Indeed, the save field is not even guaranteed to be accurate beyond it is 0min when DST is not in effect and not 0min when it is.
In the first part of the question you hinted that you might want the time zone abbreviation too.  The easiest way to get that is to stream out zt in place of zt.get_local_time().  This will print out the same time, but with the abbreviation:
    cout << "output time:" << zt << endl;

Output:
input time: 2021-03-14 00:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 00:00:00 EST
input time: 2021-03-14 01:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 01:00:00 EST
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00 EDT
input time: 2021-03-14 03:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00 EDT

Either way, this program is very nearly the identity operation.  What goes in comes out, except during daylight saving starting:
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00

This local time does not actually exist.  Normally this line would throw an exception with such input:
    zt = {zt.get_time_zone(), tp, choose::latest};

nonexistent_local_time:
2021-03-14 02:00:00 is in a gap between
2021-03-14 02:00:00 EST and
2021-03-14 03:00:00 EDT which are both equivalent to
2021-03-14 07:00:00 UTC

but because of the choose::latest, the program maps the nonexistent local_time 2021-03-14 02:00:00 to 2021-03-14 07:00:00 UTC and then on print out maps it back to the existing (and equivalent) local_time 2021-03-14 03:00:00 EDT.
When DST ends there will be two local 1am time points and the choose::latest directive will choose the second mapping (1am EST) instead of throwing an exception.
input time: 2021-11-07 00:00:00
output time:2021-11-07 00:00:00 EDT
input time: 2021-11-07 01:00:00
output time:2021-11-07 01:00:00 EST  // not EDT!
input time: 2021-11-07 02:00:00
output time:2021-11-07 02:00:00 EST

Update
And after reading this again, and thanks to the editors for the cleanup and formatting, I see that my answer above may be off (not sure) so trying again.
If the input is always offset -05:00, and the output should be in America/New_York, then there is yet another way to handle that detail.  There exists an IANA timezone that is always offset -05:00: "Etc/GMT+5".
And so the problem becomes:  Translate local times in "Etc/GMT+5" to the equivalent local times in "America/New_York".
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "date/tz.h"

int main() 
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    auto tz_src = locate_zone("Etc/GMT+5");
    auto tz_dst = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    for (local_seconds tp = local_days{March/14/2021};
         tp <= local_days{March/14/2021} + 3h; tp += 1h)
    {
        std::cout << "input time: " << tp << std::endl;

        zoned_time zt{tz_dst, zoned_time{tz_src, tp}};        
        cout << "output time:" << zt.get_local_time() << endl;
    }
}

Above the input time_point is paired with "Etc/GMT+5" by forming a zoned_time and then that is used as the "time instant" input to a second zoned_time anchored to "America/New_York".  The output is now:
input time: 2021-03-14 00:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 00:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 01:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 01:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 02:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 03:00:00
input time: 2021-03-14 03:00:00
output time:2021-03-14 04:00:00

I'm not positive which one of these answers is the desired outcome, however this last one matches that in the question character for character.
Dealing with time can be tricky, and often the trickiest part is defining the problem.  Once the problem is specified precisely, chrono can be used to provide the solution.

Thanks for answer. Your second program gives me exactly what I want. But as a input I have only "America/New_York" in timezone. How to get etc/GMT+5 from that? Any other alternative to get it with using "America/New_York" ? My date time input is always DST neutral as its wall clock time (no dst involved)

I'm not aware of any technique that is always going to work on all time zones throughout all time.  The reality is that there will always be some time zone that does something completely unexpected at some point in time.  Like double daylight saving, or permanent daylight saving.  Or a change from a non-daylight  saving offset to another non-daylight saving offset.  If you can restrict your set of target timezones down to a manageable several over a period in which they have predictable behavior, you could build an a-priori map: America/New_York -> etc/GMT+5, for example.
